# Variable within for loop in python

Tags: python, variables, for-loop, control-flow

If I have a variable generated by a for loop, is there a way to reference the same variable that was generated by the previous loop iteration from the current loop iteration? Here is a pseudocode of what I am trying to do:

```
for i in list:
    var = generate(i)
    do stuff with var
    if(condition = true):
        do stuff to the previously generated var
```

Comment: What do you do if the condition is true, but there is no previous element? That is, on the first iteration of the loop, there is no previously generated value to do anything with.

Comment: Well, the pseudo-code I provided is very basic just to grasp the concept. my actual code contains different if statements and I was able to make the solution proposed work according to the context that I'm dealing with.

Comment: Sure, and the solutions are good. But an alternative approach (using `zip`) is cleaner and more pythonic *if* you aren't worried about the above case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's less pseudo-codish code to achieve that.

```
old = None
for i in list:
    var = generate(i)
    do_stuff(var)
    if old is not None:
        do_other_stuff(old)
    old = var
```

Comment: Couldn't you replace `if old is not None:` with `if old:` and make it cleaner?

Comment: Nope, what if `old == 0`?

Comment: Very well noted. But what is `var==None`?

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
previous = None
for i in list:
    var = generate(i)
    ...do stuff with var...
    if ...condition...:
        ...do stuff with previous...
    previous = var
```

Note: `...condition...` shouldn't be `True` for `previous is None`.